# Store Web Form in RoR Then Display On Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails, but I'm familiar with other programming languages.

I have created a simple RoR application that integrates with the Braintree API. I am trying to add more form fields to collect customer information like Name and Email. Then I would like to be able to go to a page (localhost:3000/customers) to see the list of all customers stored in the database.

I know how to access form post data (params[:field]), and I am already handling the entire post, with the existing Braintree integration. I am a little unclear on how the RoR database thing works. But I would like to store this form data in the database, then print it all out. I'm sure this can't be very hard.

If someone could point me in the right direction, or at least to a similar tutorial, it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little too vague. The gist of it is that you will need a `model` to interact with the database via `ActiveRecord`. You might need to configure your `<yourapp>/config/database.yml` if you are using database other than the default `sqlite` database.

Following tutorials should get you up to speed.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#top